# Keyset Pagination for Spring Data JDBCs Pageable

Tags: pagination, spring-data-jdbc

AFAIK, the [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) class supports only LIMIT/OFFSET based paging. However, while being a quite universal solution, it comes with some downsides as outlined here https://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2020.html#August_10_2020

*Keyset Pagination* (aka *Seek Method* or *Cursor-based Pagination*) has some benefits in terms of performance and behavior during concurrent data inserts and deletes. For details see

- https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset
- http://allyouneedisbackend.com/blog/2017/09/24/the-sql-i-love-part-1-scanning-large-table/
- https://slack.engineering/evolving-api-pagination-at-slack-1c1f644f8e12
- https://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2020.html#August_17_2020

So, are there any plans to support this pagination method, e.g. via `Pageable<KeyType>` and `getKey()` that then gets incorporated into the SQLs WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This possibility was discussed in the team and while not considered urgent it is something we would like to offer eventually.

The first step would be to provide support for this in Spring Data Commons, i.e. a persistence store independent API. The issue for this is [DATACMNS-1729](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1729)